# PiCamera through Terminal (write)

Tags: python, pi-3, camera

I am trying to take a picture using my Raspberry Pi 3 & Raspberry Pi Camera from the terminal of my Mac laptop. I connect through SSH w/my IP address, then enter Python, then:

```
>>> import picamera
>>> camera = picamera.PiCamera()
```

After entering this the camera light comes on.

```
>>> camera.capture = (“test_image.jpg”)
```

After entering this I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'PiCamera' object attribute 'capture' is read-only

I get no errors using `camera.capture(“test_image.jpg”)` in Python on Raspian.

How do I enable the Mac write privileges for `camera.capture`, if that’s what I need to do? I know it must be something simple, but just haven’t found the right keywords to search.

Comment: Are you after a solution to your Python problem, or a solution to take pictures? The inbuilt `raspistill` command should do what you want.

Comment: I was trying to take a photo remotely & import it to my mac using ssh. Sorry that wasn't clear. Total Noobie & made a typo. Problem solved. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working directly on the Pi you enter:

```
camera.capture("test_image.jpg")
```

Working though the SSH session from your Mac you enter:

```
camera.capture = ("test_image.jpg")
```

Notice the `=` sign in the line you entered on Mac. This results in an error, because you try to assign value to the `capture()` method of the `PiCamera` object.

SSH connection plays no role here. Everything you enter is executed and interpreted on the Pi.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out. That's exactly what was wrong.